# Why does my Admob BannerAd doesn't show up? Unity Android

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob

I have made a custom BannerAd position and size formulas and it works pretty good in the Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge as it's resolution is 1440 x 2560 pixels (height x width)(landscape) which makes the BannerAd size should be 254 x 83 pixels (width x height) and the position should 372, 213 (x, y).

This is the formula that I used to get these values dynamically for every screen size (resolution).

```
int w, h, x, y;
    w = Mathf.FloorToInt(Screen.width / 10.07f);
    h = Mathf.FloorToInt(Screen.height / 17.3f);
    x = Mathf.FloorToInt(Screen.width / 6.8f);
    y = Mathf.FloorToInt(Screen.height / 6.7f);
```

PS: it works just fine in a Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge. Here is a preview:
[image]

I tested the exact same application in a ZTE Blade L3 and I got nothing, the other types of ads work just fine but this.
Here is a logcat that I snapshotted to get some more informations.

```
--------- beginning of system

--------- beginning of main

I/Unity   ( 3589): SystemInfo CPU = ARMv7 VFPv3 NEON, Cores = 4, Memory = 964mb

I/Unity   ( 3589): SystemInfo ARM big.LITTLE configuration: 4 big (mask: 15), 0 little (mask: 0)

I/Unity   ( 3589): ApplicationInfo com.pfeHY.sevenApocalypseSins version 1.6 build d3f911aa-1262-4fd6-90fb-2e0bd54ecee0

I/Unity   ( 3589): Built from '2017.3/release' branch, Version '2017.3.1f1 (fc1d3344e6ea)', Build type 'Release', Scripting Backend 'mono'

E/Unity   ( 3589): [EGL] eglChooseConfig(m_EGLDisplay, configAttribs, NULL, 0, &eglConfigCount): EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE: An unrecognized attribute or attribute value was passed in the attribute list.

E/Unity   ( 3589): Stacktrace is not supported on this platform. 

E/Unity   ( 3589): (Filename: /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/GfxDevice/egl/ConfigEGL.cpp Line: 376)

E/Unity   ( 3589): 

E/Unity   ( 3589): [EGL] eglChooseConfig(m_EGLDisplay, configAttribs, NULL, 0, &eglConfigCount): EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE: An unrecognized attribute or attribute value was passed in the attribute list.

E/Unity   ( 3589): Stacktrace is not supported on this platform. 

E/Unity   ( 3589): (Filename: /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/GfxDevice/egl/ConfigEGL.cpp Line: 376)

E/Unity   ( 3589): 

E/Unity   ( 3589): [EGL] eglChooseConfig(m_EGLDisplay, configAttribs, NULL, 0, &eglConfigCount): EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE: An unrecognized attribute or attribute value was passed in the attribute list.

E/Unity   ( 3589): Stacktrace is not supported on this platform. 

E/Unity   ( 3589): (Filename: /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/GfxDevice/egl/ConfigEGL.cpp Line: 376)

E/Unity   ( 3589): 

E/Unity   ( 3589): [EGL] eglChooseConfig(m_EGLDisplay, configAttribs, NULL, 0, &eglConfigCount): EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE: An unrecognized attribute or attribute value was passed in the attribute list.

E/Unity   ( 3589): Stacktrace is not supported on this platform. 

E/Unity   ( 3589): (Filename: /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/GfxDevice/egl/ConfigEGL.cpp Line: 376)

E/Unity   ( 3589): 

E/Unity   ( 3589): [EGL] eglChooseConfig(m_EGLDisplay, configAttribs, NULL, 0, &eglConfigCount): EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE: An unrecognized attribute or attribute value was passed in the attribute list.

E/Unity   ( 3589): Stacktrace is not supported on this platform. 

E/Unity   ( 3589): (Filename: /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/GfxDevice/egl/ConfigEGL.cpp Line: 376)

E/Unity   ( 3589): 

E/Unity   ( 3589): [EGL] eglChooseConfig(m_EGLDisplay, configAttribs, NULL, 0, &eglConfigCount): EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE: An unrecognized attribute or attribute value was passed in the attribute list.

E/Unity   ( 3589): Stacktrace is not supported on this platform. 

E/Unity   ( 3589): (Filename: /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/GfxDevice/egl/ConfigEGL.cpp Line: 376)

E/Unity   ( 3589): 

D/Unity   ( 3589): GL_EXT_debug_marker GL_OES_texture_npot GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture GL_OES_standard_derivatives GL_OES_EGL_image GL_OES_depth24 GL_ARM_rgba8 GL_ARM_mali_shader_binary GL_OES_depth_texture GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888 GL_OES_vertex_half_float GL_EXT_blend_minmax GL_OES_EGL_image_external GL_OES_EGL_sync GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8 GL_EXT_multisampled_render_to_texture GL_EXT_discard_framebuffer GL_OES_get_program_binary GL_ARM_mali_program_binary GL_EXT_shader_texture_lod GL_EXT_robustness GL_OES_depth_texture_cube_map GL_KHR_debug 

W/Unity   ( 3589): OnLevelWasLoaded was found on GameManager

W/Unity   ( 3589): This message has been deprecated and will be removed in a later version of Unity.

W/Unity   ( 3589): Add a delegate to SceneManager.sceneLoaded instead to get notifications after scene loading has completed

W/Unity   ( 3589): Stacktrace is not supported on this platform. 

W/Unity   ( 3589): (Filename:  Line: 375)

W/Unity   ( 3589): 

I/Unity   ( 3589): FMOD Studio: Device ZTE ZTE Blade L3 classed as MobileLow

I/Unity   ( 3589): Screen size

I/Unity   ( 3589): width=854, height=480

I/Unity   ( 3589): BannerAd stats

I/Unity   ( 3589): x=125, y=71, w=84, h=27

E/Unity   ( 3589): AndroidJavaException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.ViewTreeObserver com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView.getViewTreeObserver()' on a null object reference

E/Unity   ( 3589): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.ViewTreeObserver com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView.getViewTreeObserver()' on a null object reference

E/Unity   ( 3589):  at com.google.unity.ads.Banner.destroy(Banner.java:328)

E/Unity   ( 3589):  at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.nativeRender(Native Method)

E/Unity   ( 3589):  at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.c(Unknown Source)

E/Unity   ( 3589):  at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$c$1.handleMessage(Unknown Source)

E/Unity   ( 3589):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)

E/Unity   ( 3589):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:189)

E/Unity   ( 3589):  at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$c.run(Unknown Source)

E/Unity   ( 3589):   at UnityEngine.AndroidJNISafe.CheckException () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

E/Unity   ( 3589):   at UnityEngine.AndroidJNISafe.CallVoidMethod (IntPtr obj, IntPtr methodID, UnityEngine.jvalue[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

E/Unity   ( 3589):   at UnityEngine.

E/Unity   ( 3589): AndroidJavaException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.ViewTreeObserver com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView.getViewTreeObserver()' on a null object reference

E/Unity   ( 3589): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.ViewTreeObserver com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView.getViewTreeObserver()' on a null object reference

E/Unity   ( 3589):  at com.google.unity.ads.Banner.destroy(Banner.java:328)

E/Unity   ( 3589):  at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.nativeRender(Native Method)

E/Unity   ( 3589):  at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.c(Unknown Source)

E/Unity   ( 3589):  at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$c$1.handleMessage(Unknown Source)

E/Unity   ( 3589):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)

E/Unity   ( 3589):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:189)

E/Unity   ( 3589):  at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$c.run(Unknown Source)

E/Unity   ( 3589):   at UnityEngine.AndroidJNISafe.CheckException () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

E/Unity   ( 3589):   at UnityEngine.AndroidJNISafe.CallVoidMethod (IntPtr obj, IntPtr methodID, UnityEngine.jvalue[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

E/Unity   ( 3589):   at UnityEngine.
```